# IOTA Whitepaper: What is N in Section 3?

Tags: iota-network, white-paper

The IOTA Whitepaper refers to N but never defines what N means. Can anyone tell me what the N means in Section 3 and explain in words what the equation means? Thanks!

> Observe that at any fixed time t the set of transactions that were
>   tips at some At least in the case where the nodes moment s ∈ [ t,t +
>   h(Lo,**N**)] typically constitutes a cutset. Any path from a transaction
>   issued at time t′ > t to the genesis must pass through this set

Comment: Also, you may want to register on https://iotatangle.slack.com and join #tanglemath, to get questions like this one answered in a more informal context.

Comment: I am not sure how to join Iota slack.  It seems like I need the admin to give me an invite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter *N* was defined in an earlier version of the whitepaper as "total number of transactions". However, the dependency of *h* on *L* and *N* (as seen in your quote) has since been removed, and all the references to *N* **should** have been updated.

Bottom line, it seems like a typo and you can think of *h(L,N)* as just *h*.